# Cannot find 'ApplicationDelegate' in scope

Tags: ios, swift

I am installing the Facebook Graph API and Im currently stuck on the following. It seems like I am unable to find the Application Delegate from the Scene Delegate.

> If you are using iOS 13 or above please add the following method to
> your SceneDelegate

```
// Swift
//
// SceneDelegate.swift

func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) {
    guard let url = URLContexts.first?.url else {
        return
    }

    ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(
        UIApplication.shared,
        open: url,
        sourceApplication: nil,
        annotation: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.annotation]
    )
}
```

When I apply the above I get the following error.

```
Cannot find 'ApplicationDelegate' in scope
```

Comment: are you imported the `import FBSDKCoreKit` and `import FacebookCore` in your SceneDelegate

Comment: Thanks that seems to have worked, forgot to add it to that file

Comment: Faced same issue just import FBSDKCoreKit in SceneDelegate file. Thanks @Anbu.Karthik

Answer (score 21, accepted):

import FBSDKCoreKit in your SceneDelegate And It Works Fine

Comment: If I do this, I get the error "Missing required module 'LegacyCore'"

Comment: @Pigpocket That's probably an issue with the way you're building the project.